# PHP: Use (or not) 'utf8_encode' in combination with setting BOM to \xEF\xBB\xBF

Tags: php, utf-8, fopen, fwrite

When using the following code:

```
$myString = 'some contents';    
$fh=fopen('newfile.txt',"w");
fwrite($fh, "\xEF\xBB\xBF" . $myString);
```

Is there any point of using PHP functions to first encode the text ($myString in the example) e.g. like running `utf8_encode($myString);` or similar `iconv()` commands?

Assuming that the BOM `\xEF\xBB\xBF` is first inputted into the file and that UTF8 represents practically all characters in the world I don't see any potential failure scenarion of creating a file this way. In other words I don't see any case where any major text editor wouldn't be able to interpret the newly created file corectly, displaying all characters as intended. This even if `$myString` would be a PHP `$_POST` variable from a HTML form. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your source file is `UTF-8` encoded, then the string `$myString` is also `UTF-8` encoded, you don't need to convert it. Otherwise, you need to use `iconv()` to convert the encoding first before write it to the file.

And note `utf8_encode()` is used  to encode an ISO-8859-1 string to UTF-8.

Comment: What do you mean by 'source file' in this context?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `utf8_encode` will only convert `ISO-8859-1` encoded strings.

In general, given that PHP only supports a [256 char](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details) character set, you will need to utf-8 encode any string containing non-ASCII characters before writing it to UTF-8.

The BOM is optional (most text file readers now will scan the file for its encoding).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)

> The Unicode Standard permits the BOM in UTF-8,[2] but does not require
>   or recommend for or against its use